# Replace a text in a line with text in another text file

Tags: shell

Please let me know how to replace a group of text in a file with text in another file.

Example: In file 1 the entry is,

```
Server: Hardcoded.large.net:5600
The above is the entry for the servers for HAXDTS.
```

Entry in file 2 is,

```
Adhoc.large.net:5600
HAXDTSij
```

I need to replace the entry "Hardcoded.large.net:5600" with the entry from File2, and `HAXDTS` with `HAXDTSij`

The file should be modified as

```
Server:Adhoc.large.net:5600
The above is the entry for the servers for HAXDTSij
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't have enough information in file 2 to be able to do the mapping automatically.  There's no data about what pattern in file 1 should be replaced with Adhoc.large.net:5600 from file 2.  There's no data about what pattern in file 1 should be replaced with HAXDTSij.  What should happen if file 1 contains `Server: AlternativeHardcode.large.net:5600` and `The above is for HAXDTSxy.`?  Should the names be mapped or not, and if so, what should they be mapped to?

Comment: Is the above, the only contents in the files?

Comment: Need to replace Hardcoded.large.net:5600 with entry in the first line of file2.....HAXDTS with second line of file2.. passing the text to be replaced from another file...

Answer (score 1):

`sed -i "s/Hardcoded/Adhoc/" <file1>`

`sed -i "s/.*HAXDTS/HAXDTSij/" <file1>`

You should backup file1 in case you want to revert it.

Throw that into a loop if you have a lot of files you need to do this to.

Comment: not like this actually.... suppose we have many file with same entry then placing the target entry in one text file and run the script should replace the text in all files....passing the values from one file to another.......